# How do I make sphinx recognize packages that the source code recognizes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am using Sphinx to document a web-scraping project I am working on with Python 3.9.  As part of the process I read an API key in from a yaml file.  The code works fine when I test it; however, when I try to document the code with sphinx I get an error telling me that autodoc cannot import yaml because it does not recognize it.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you use different `python` instances when you run the code and when you run Sphinx? Do you use a virtualenv in one case but not the other? Have you tried `autodoc_mock_imports = ["yaml"]`? (see https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_mock_imports)

Comment: How do you "document the code with sphinx"? What is the exact error message? Please update your question with this information.